# How to force to not download pdf in iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

```
<body>
<iframe src='howto.pdf' height='800px' width='500px'> </iframe>
</body>
```

This code works fine(show iframe)when i just simple open howto.php in a browser. But when i open this php file in localhostserver it doesn't show the iframe, idm poup and say us to download the file. (( i save this file as howto.php ))

Comment: show us your code then.

Comment: <?php include_once 'header.php'; ?> <body> <iframe src='howto.pdf' height='600px' width='850px'> </iframe> </body>

Comment: not in comments, show in your question, and what is located in your header file, what is located in your howto.php file..

Comment: The cide i comment is howto.php and whenever i try to add php code in question it says me code not formated perfect and even after removing the header.php link idm still popup and ask us to download

Comment: has your pdf a public url?

Answer (score 3):

if your pdf has a public url you can use google pdf viewer in this way

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=yourPdfUrl&embedded=true" style="width:800px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

replace `yourPdfUrl` with your real pdf url e.g. `http://www.example.com/myDoc.pdf`