# Angular - View PDF from two splitted links

Tags: angular

Actually I am trying to view a PDF file but the main challenges are:

I am using Restful API where I am not authorized to make any modification

I am having two APIs (i.to get uploaded PDF link) (ii.upload PDF)

After uploading a PDF by using (ii.upload PDF) API I am getting a link eg.usr_doc/13213.pdf

Then I have to add one static URL before the document link eg.domain.com/users/usr_doc/13213.pdf to complete the absolute path of PDF file.

After that If I am using embed,object,iframe to display the PDF it is automatically downloading the PDF file instead of displaying.

I know after reading this question you may feel this is old but I have tried `ng2-pdf-viewer`, `ngx-extendedpdf-viewer`.

Please help me

```
    <iframe width="500" height="600" [src]="staticUrl+docUrl" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
    <embed [src]="staticUrl+docUrl" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="550px" />
```

Comment: Share Your Code.

Comment: I have added the iframe and embed code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally, I got the solution for my question**

Here I am not using any PDF viewer, I am using only iframe which really works awesome

This is for normal html which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711432/how-to-force-to-not-download-pdf-in-iframe)

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=yourPdfUrl&embedded=true" style="width:800px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

then I modified it for Angular

**app.component.html**

```
<h2>View PDF</h2>

<iframe [src]="sanitizedLink" style="width:800px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  staticUrl ="https://storage.googleapis.com/usr_doc/";

  googleLink:string ="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=";

  sanitizedLink:any;

  pdflink ='usr_dat/doc/a69046d21a29_202002265656.pdf';

  embede='&embedded=true';

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.sanitizedLink = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl( this.googleLink+this.staticUrl+this.pdflink+this.embede);
  }
}
```

Now it is Displaying PDF without auto download
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]Hope this helps...

**pdf-viewer.comonent.html**

```
<embed [src]="url" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```

**pdf-viewer.comonent.ts**

```
url: SafeUrl;
constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.url = 
 this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf- 
 viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Actually I have already tried with domsanitization which is also auto downloading

Comment: This is the working example, please refer the image attached